# com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

This is the frist time I am trying XStream. But when I try to parse my xml file i am getting this exception :

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field xmlread.Type.type
---- Debugging information ----
field               : type
class               : xmlread.Type
required-type       : xmlread.Type
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /root/type
line number         : 10
version             : 1.4.8
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.handleUnknownField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:501)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:357)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:263)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at xmlread.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

So we can see that the error is on row 10 in my Type class. 
And row 10 is the this line : @XStreamAlias("root")

```
package xmlread;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

@XStreamAlias("root")
public class Type {

    @XStreamAlias("INFO")
    private Info info;
    @XStreamAlias("OBJECT_TYPE")
    private String objectType;
    @XStreamAlias("PROP")
    private Properties prop;
    @XStreamAlias("PARAM")
    private List<Parameters> param;

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "type")
    private List typeList = new ArrayList();

    // metodo construtor
    public Type() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //Constructor, Getters and setters
    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    public Properties getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(Properties prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    public List<Parameters> getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(List<Parameters> param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public List getTypeList() {
        return typeList;
    }

    public void setTypeList(List typeList) {
        this.typeList = typeList;
    }
}
```

And the xml looks like this :

```
<root>
    <info>
        <CORE_NAME>DataModel_Core</CORE_NAME> 
        <CORE_VERSION>..</CORE_VERSION> 
        <CORE_PRODUCT_ID>...</CORE_PRODUCT_ID> 
        <ADAPTATION_NAME /> 
        <ADAPTATION_VERSION /> 
        <ADAPTATION_PRODUCT_ID /> 
    </info>
    <type>
        <OBJECT_TYPE>data</OBJECT_TYPE>
        <prop>
            <DESCRIPTION>Site parameters</DESCRIPTION> 
            <PARENT>NULL</PARENT> 
            <VIRTUAL>0</VIRTUAL> 
            <VISIBLE>1</VISIBLE> 
            <PICTURE>NULL</PICTURE> 
            <HELP>10008</HELP> 
            <MIN_NO>1</MIN_NO> 
            <MAX_NO>1</MAX_NO> 
            <NAME_FORMAT>NULL</NAME_FORMAT> 
        </prop>
        <param>
            <PARAMETER>nidRbc</PARAMETER> 
            <DATA_TYPE>INTEGER</DATA_TYPE> 
            <DESCRIPTION>RBC identity</DESCRIPTION> 
            <MIN_NO>1</MIN_NO> 
            <MAX_NO>1</MAX_NO> 
            <ORDER1>1</ORDER1> 
            <NESTED>0</NESTED> 
            <DEFAULT1>NULL</DEFAULT1> 
            <FORMAT>0:16382</FORMAT> 
        </param>
    </type>
</root>
```

And my other classes looks like this :

```
package xmlread;

import java.io.*;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStreamException;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            try {

                FileReader reader = new FileReader("enderecos.xml");

                //String representacao = xstream.toXML(aluno);

                XStream xstream = new XStream();
                xstream.processAnnotations(Properties.class);
                xstream.processAnnotations(Parameters.class);
                xstream.processAnnotations(ObjType.class);
                xstream.processAnnotations(Type.class);
                Type data = (Type)xstream.fromXML(reader);
                //Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);

                System.out.println(data);
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XStreamException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    ____________________________________________________________

package xmlread;

import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

    @XStreamAlias("PARAM")
    public class Parameters {

        @XStreamAlias("DATATYPE")
        private String datatype;
        @XStreamAlias("DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;
        @XStreamAlias("MIN_NO")
        private String min_no;
        @XStreamAlias("MAX_NO")
        private String max_no;
        @XStreamAlias("ORDER1")
        private String order1;
        @XStreamAlias("NESTED")
        private String nested;
        @XStreamAlias("DEFAULT1")
        private String default1;
        @XStreamAlias("FORMAT")
        private String format;
        @XStreamAlias("PARAMETER")
        private List<Parameters> parameter;

        public Parameters(String datatype, String description, String min_no,
                String max_no, String order1, String nested, String default1,
                String format, List<Parameters> parameter) {
            super();

            setDatatype(datatype);
            setDescription(description);
            setMin_no(min_no);
            setMax_no(max_no);
            setOrder1(order1);
            setNested(nested);
            setDefault1(default1);
            setFormat(format);
            setParameter(parameter);

        } // Getters and setters..

        public Parameters() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public String getDatatype() {
            return datatype;
        }

        public void setDatatype(String datatype) {
            this.datatype = datatype;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getMin_no() {
            return min_no;
        }

        public void setMin_no(String min_no) {
            this.min_no = min_no;
        }

        public String getMax_no() {
            return max_no;
        }

        public void setMax_no(String max_no) {
            this.max_no = max_no;
        }

        public String getOrder1() {
            return order1;
        }

        public void setOrder1(String order1) {
            this.order1 = order1;
        }

        public String getNested() {
            return nested;
        }

        public void setNested(String nested) {
            this.nested = nested;
        }

        public String getDefault1() {
            return default1;
        }

        public void setDefault1(String default1) {
            this.default1 = default1;
        }

        public String getFormat() {
            return format;
        }

        public void setFormat(String format) {
            this.format = format;
        }

        public List<Parameters> getParameter() {
            return parameter;
        }

        public void setParameter(List<Parameters> parameter) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
    }

    ____________________________________________________________


    package xmlread;

    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

    @XStreamAlias("prop")
    public class Properties {

        @XStreamAlias("DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;
        @XStreamAlias("PARENT")
        private String parent;
        @XStreamAlias("VIRTUAL")
        private String virtual;
        @XStreamAlias("VISIBLE")
        private String visible;
        @XStreamAlias("PICTURE")
        private String picture;
        @XStreamAlias("HELP")
        private String help;
        @XStreamAlias("MIN_NO")
        private String min_no;
        @XStreamAlias("MAX_NO")
        private String max_no;
        @XStreamAlias("NAME_FORMAT")
        private String name_format;

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(String parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public String getVirtual() {
            return virtual;
        }

        public void setVirtual(String virtual) {
            this.virtual = virtual;
        }

        public String getVisible() {
            return visible;
        }

        public void setVisible(String visible) {
            this.visible = visible;
        }

        public String getPicture() {
            return picture;
        }

        public void setPicture(String picture) {
            this.picture = picture;
        }

        public String getHelp() {
            return help;
        }

        public void setHelp(String help) {
            this.help = help;
        }

        public String getMin_no() {
            return min_no;
        }

        public void setMin_no(String min_no) {
            this.min_no = min_no;
        }

        public String getMax_no() {
            return max_no;
        }

        public void setMax_no(String max_no) {
            this.max_no = max_no;
        }

        public String getName_format() {
            return name_format;
        }

        public void setName_format(String name_format) {
            this.name_format = name_format;
        }

        public static void setInstance(Properties instance) {
            Properties.instance = instance;
        }

        public static Properties instance = null;

        public static Properties getInstance() {

            if (instance == null) {

                instance = new Properties();

            }

            return instance;
        }

        public Properties() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }

    ____________________________________________________________

package xmlread;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

@XStreamAlias("INFO")
public class Info {

    @XStreamAlias("CORE_NAME")
    private String core_name;
    @XStreamAlias("CORE_VERSION")
    private String core_version;
    @XStreamAlias("CORE_PRODUCT_ID")
    private String core_product_id;
    @XStreamAlias("ADAPTATION_NAME")
    private String adaptation_name;
    @XStreamAlias("ADAPTATION_VERSION")
    private String adaptation_version;
    @XStreamAlias("ADAPTATION_PRODUCT_ID")
    private String adaptation_product_id;

    public Info(String core_name, String core_version, String core_product_id,
            String adaptation_name, String adaptation_version,
            String adaptation_product_id) {
        super();

        setCore_name(core_name);
        setCore_version(core_version);
        setCore_product_id(core_product_id);
        setAdaptation_name(adaptation_name);
        setAdaptation_version(adaptation_version);
        setAdaptation_product_id(adaptation_product_id);
    }

    public String getCore_name() {
        return core_name;
    }

    public void setCore_name(String core_name) {
        this.core_name = core_name;
    }

    public String getCore_version() {
        return core_version;
    }

    public void setCore_version(String core_version) {
        this.core_version = core_version;
    }

    public String getCore_product_id() {
        return core_product_id;
    }

    public void setCore_product_id(String core_product_id) {
        this.core_product_id = core_product_id;
    }

    public String getAdaptation_name() {
        return adaptation_name;
    }

    public void setAdaptation_name(String adaptation_name) {
        this.adaptation_name = adaptation_name;
    }

    public String getAdaptation_version() {
        return adaptation_version;
    }

    public void setAdaptation_version(String adaptation_version) {
        this.adaptation_version = adaptation_version;
    }

    public String getAdaptation_product_id() {
        return adaptation_product_id;
    }

    public void setAdaptation_product_id(String adaptation_product_id) {
        this.adaptation_product_id = adaptation_product_id;
    }

}

    ____________________________________________________________

package xmlread;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

@XStreamAlias("OBJECT_TYPE")
public class ObjType {

    @XStreamAlias("OBJECT_TYPE")
    private String objectType;

    public ObjType() {

    } // Getters and setters

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }


}
```

Whats the cause of this error?

Comment: You are missing 1 element called "type" which is there in your xml but not in your java class. Try adding that. Also your mapping seems inappropriate to me. I would create a class which is mapped with "root" within which I would have "info" object, "type" object within "type" I would have object_type, param and props. P.S I haven't used XStream but trying currently to implement it. :)

Comment: I add an element called "type" in Type.class.

@XStreamAlias("TYPE")
private String type;

When I try to parse my xml file i am getting this out:
xmlread.Type@6c3708b3.

Do it wrong? Where is xml tags?

Comment: have a look at this link you will get some idea about the xml corrosponding class structure http://pastebin.com/20zD1WkS

Comment: glad I could help, it would be nice if you have pasted your own code. Mine is a bit rough version.

Answer (score 1):

```
package xmlread;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

@XStreamAlias("root")
public class SomeOtherClass {

    @XStreamAlias("INFO")
    private Info info;

         @XStreamAlias("TYPE")
         private Type type;

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "type")
    private List typeList = new ArrayList();

    // metodo construtor
    public SomeOtherClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //Constructor, Getters and setters
         public void setType(Type type){
                this.type = type;
         }

         public Type getType() {
                return this.type;
         }


    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

}


class Type {

         @XStreamAlias("OBJECT_TYPE")
    private String objectType;

    @XStreamAlias("PROP")
    private Properties prop;


    @XStreamAlias("PARAM")
    private List<Parameters> param;

        public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    public Properties getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(Properties prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    public List<Parameters> getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(List<Parameters> param) {
        this.param = param;
    }


}
```