# CannotResolveClassException on using XStream on nested XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream

So after looking for a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983333/how-can-i-get-the-values-of-the-nested-objects-in-xstream), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438124/xstream-cannotresolveclassexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050537/com-thoughtworks-xstream-converters-reflection-abstractreflectionconverterunkno), I'm still unable to parse a Java object from an XML. The XML has nested tags and I have designed my classes accordingly, but I cannot find out where I'm going wrong.

Following is my XML

```
 private static final String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<author>\n" +
            "<name>Auro</name>\n" +
            "<id>123</id>\n" +
            "<books>\n" +
            "<name>C++</name>\n" +
            "<status>published</status>\n" +
            "</books>\n" +
            "<books>\n" +
            "<name>Java</name>\n" +
            "<status>unpublished</status>\n" +
            "</books>\n" +
            "</author>";
```

The **Author** class

```
public class Author {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private List<Books> books;

    public Author() {}

    public Author(String name, String id, List<Books> books) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.books = books;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Books> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }


    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Books> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String res = "Author_Name: " + name + " -- " + "Author_ID: " + id + " ";
        for (Books book : books) {
            res = res + book.toString();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The **Books.java** class

```
public class Books {

    private String name;
    private String status;

    public Books() {}

    public Books(String name, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "Book_Name: " + name + " -- " + "Book_Status: " + status + "\n";
    }
}
```

And following is how I am calling the method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/parse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String parse() {

        System.out.print("THIS GOT TRIGGERED!!");
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.alias("author",Author.class);
        xStream.alias("books",Books.class);

        Author author = (Author) xStream.fromXML(XML);

        System.out.print(author.toString());

        return author.toString();

    }
```

But my app is crashing with the following errors:

```
-- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : name
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /author/books/name
line number         : 6
class[1]            : blahblah.testSpringboot.models.Author
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------] with root cause

com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:98) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:91) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:85) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:80) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1076) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at blahblah.testSpringboot.controllers.TestParser.parse(TestParser.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Is it with my XML or is it something I missed in my method?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to change your xml input:

```
...
<books>
<book>
    <name>C++</name>
    <status>published</status>
</book>
<book>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <status>unpublished</status>
</book>
</books>
...
```

and

```
xStream.alias("book",Book.class); // rename Books class to Book
```

The problem at the moment is:
You have a list called "books" in your author class. That list is addressed by your "books" tag. Then in the xml the next tag is "name", but the first element in your books list is expected to be a Book (not a name).